# How to select dataframe column values in a specified range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/Intel_AI4Y/My Drive/Intel_AI4Y_Colab/Module_16/data/Students_Score1.csv")

names = ["Student No." ,"Hours spent studying in a day", "Mathematics score", "English score","Science score"]

df.columns = names

Mathematics_score = df.iloc[:, 0]

df = df[~df.iloc[:, 0].between(100, 0, inclusive=False)]

print(df.describe())

print (df.info())
```

I'm trying to remove erroneous data from Mathematics score, value that is below 0 or above 100. I'm not sure how I'm suppose to go about coding this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

- `df = df[~df.iloc[:, 0].between(100, 0, inclusive=False)]` is almost correct
- [`pandas.Series.between`](http://pandas.Series.between) requires a left and right boundary, which should be `0` and `100` respectively.
- `~` is `not` so in effect `df.iloc[:, 0].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)` returns everything between 0 and 100, but `~df.iloc[:, 0].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)` return values `<=0` and `>=100`.
- To return values between 0 and 100, use `df[df.iloc[:, 0].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)]`
- Also see [Pandas: Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- See [Pandas: Selection by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) for the proper use of `.iloc`. `df.iloc[:, 0]` means you have selected all rows, `:` and the column at index `0`. My sample data only has one column, so index `0`. You need to verify the index for your column of interest.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [np.random.randint(-100, 200) for _ in range(500)]})

# values between 0 and 100
df[df.iloc[:, 0].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)]

 values
     43
     37
     55
     41
     35

# values <=0 or >=100
df[~df.iloc[:, 0].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)]

 values
    -92
    180
    -21
    -47
    -34
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data frame comes with headers. I would really suggest to use a mask filter as follows.

```
df = df[(df['Mathematics score'] > 0) & (df['Mathematics score'] < 100)]
```

As suggested by @Trenton McKinney, it is true that using `iloc` sometimes is easier because you don't have to type the column name.

So, in your case, because the column `Mathematics score` is the third one, so you should do:

```
df[~df.iloc[:, 2].between(0, 100, inclusive=False)]
```